# Can a Cloudformation stack know whether it's being created or updated?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a resource with one of its properties not being a constant value. Sounds like a job for a stack parameter, except that it's a string that can take form of a Ref function in some cases. Specifically, if it's the initial creation, I want the parameter value to be a Ref to another resource, and if it's a subsequent update, I want it to be a Ref to a stack parameter. Is this possible? Is there a function or a pseudo parameter, like `AWS::CurrentAction` that can take values like `create` and `update`, or anything of that kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's something to be avoided but if you can't find any other alternative I have a workaround.

Here's an exemple with a bucket name:

```
Parameters:
  ExternalBucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: ''

Conditions:
  ExternalBucketNameSpecified:
    !Not [!Equals [!Ref ExternalBucketName, '']]


Resources:
  CFManagedBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

  SomeResource:
    Type: AWS::Resource::XYZ
    Properties:
        BucketName: !If [ExternalBucketNameSpecified, !Ref ExternalBucketNameSpecified, !Ref CFManagedBucket]
```

When it's time to use the bucket created by this stack just set the `ExternalBucketName` empty and the stack will adapt automatically.

Comment: This is actually the direction I went soon after posting the question. Thanks.